# Ember belongsTo relation disappearing with localstorage adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, local-storage, ember-data

I'm using the localstorage adapter.  I have two objects: a Flow and a Param, and a Flow `hasMany` Params, and likewise a Param `belongsTo` a flow.  I have a function in my code which duplicates another object.  When I call the function from the controller, everything works fine (and the `isSaving` bit for the parameters is false, and the `isDirty` bit is also false — so it seems like the saving is going through).

However, when I reload the page, the `belongsTo` relationship does not load although all the other relationships/attributes load fine.

This is the duplicating function:

```
// elem is the Flow I'm duplicating, newFlowJSON is the JSON I'll use to create it.
function dupFlow(_store, newFlowJSON, elem) {
  var newFlow = _store.createRecord('flow', newFlowJSON);
  newFlow.save();

  var newFlowParams;
  newFlow.get('params').then(function(params) {
    newFlowParams = params;
    elem.get('params').then(function(p) {
      var params = p.toArray();

      for (var i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
        var newParamJSON = params[i].toJSON();
        delete newParamJSON.id;
        delete newParamJSON.flow;

        var newParam = _store.createRecord('param', newParamJSON);
        newFlowParams.pushObject(newParam);
        newParam.set('flow', newFlow);
        newParam.save();
      }
    });
  });

  // couldn't figure out a good way to save the newFlow after all the params were pushed
  setTimeout(function() {
    newFlow.save();
  }, 500);
}
```

My simplified models:

```
App.Flow = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  params: DS.hasMany('param', {async: true})
});

App.Param = DS.Model.extend({
  paramName: DS.attr('string'),
  flow: DS.belongsTo('flow', {async: true})
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify. 
- Given you have an original Flow (`orgFlow`) w/ two param objects (`orgFlowParam1` & `orgFlowParam2`)
- When you have created `cloneFlow` w/ `cloneFlowParam1` & `cloneFlowParam2` from the `dupFlow` and everything looks good
- And you do a plain old F5 refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I fixed my issue by making the `belongsTo` relationship not async.  This doesn't seem like a great solution considering that Ember has said that async relationships are going to eventually become standard.  But I don't think there is a better solution right now.

The issue seems to originate in the JSONSerializer.

```
serializeBelongsTo: function(record, json, relationship) {
  var key = relationship.key;

  var belongsTo = get(record, key);

  key = this.keyForRelationship ? this.keyForRelationship(key, "belongsTo") : key;

  if (isNone(belongsTo)) {
    json[key] = belongsTo;
  } else {
    json[key] = get(belongsTo, 'id');
  }

  if (relationship.options.polymorphic) {
    this.serializePolymorphicType(record, json, relationship);
  }
},
```

Right now, the issue here is that `belongsTo.get` *doesn't return a promise*.  Therefore, in my code when the belongsTo relationship was async, `get` (which is shorthand for Ember.get) just returned undefined every time.  I think a more comprehensive solution would involve figuring out how to access the store instead of using `get`, but I'm not sure how to do this.  I'll modify this answer if I find time to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my comments timed out. I can fix them later, just wanted to make sure that pre-Refresh the Ember-Data relationships on the dups were holding up.

Have you tried `DS.belongsTo('flow',{embedded: 'always'})` ? [embedded Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html). I use them in my app, and it's a little awkward I admit, but on refresh the store models **re-acquires** what they need like a champ.

**UPDATE:**

So if you don't have a serializer setup for this, that is likely what's causing the issue, as it handles the relationship work. Toss an `FlowApp.ApplicationSerializer = DL.LSSerializer.extend();` in there. Check out this [part of the README](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter#usage). This is a small piece that's really easy to overlook.

Comment: Hm didn't seem to work.  My relationships are all async btw, so I'm wondering if they're just not loading in properly.  But there are very few objects that I'm using to test, but even after like a minute they're not loaded in.

Comment: Yeah, I had `App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.LSSerializer;` initially.  I just added the `.extend();` and unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: I looked at the data in localStorage, and there actually isn't even a flow property that's being persisted, so I'm wondering if there is an error with the serializer not working, or if my code is somehow not saving properly.  The `isDirty` bit is false right upon creating the object, but looking at the localStorage it shows that there is no flow attribute ever being saved.